# Yahoo sitemap validation

Tags: sitemap, validation, yahoo

I am trying to submit *sitemap.xml* (Index) to Yahoo Site Explorer but with no luck.
I tried using **website feed** option in the site explorer to submit the sitemap, but I got validation errors. However, when submitting the same sitemap to Google Webmaster Tools, the sitemap was validated successfully. Could it be for the fact that I am using sitemap with image tag:

```
<image:image> 
   <image:loc>http://www.domain.com/pic.jpg</image:loc> 
   <image:title>picture</image:title> 
</image:image>
```

When I tried validating the sitemap with inline tools such as http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/validate-xml-sitemap.html and http://www.w3.org/2001/03/webdata/xsv the error I received was:

> Attempt to load a schema document from
>   http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1
>   (source: new namespace) for
>   http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1,
>   failed: Not recognised as W3C XML
>   Schema or RDDL: html

However, the declaration of the sitemap I use in the top of the document is the same as suggested by Google on their official page at http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178636 :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
 <url>
```

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to supporting the sitemaps protocol at sitemaps.org Yahoo also accepts a text file with a list of URLs, if you are just trying to get information out of Site Explorer then the URL list should be the easiest for you. If you are using it as a way to get indexed faster, you should look at Bing's webmaster tool as Yahoo is now powered by Bing's index.

On a side note GSiteCrawler can crawl your website and generate a proper URL list to be submitted to YSE.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand why validating the sitemap using the validator I mentioned results an error.

Answer (score 1):

(Bit late but here goes)

Yahoo (or BING now) supports XML sitemaps protocol, but not the Google image sitemaps extension